# SSRS chart bar together

Tags: reporting-services, charts

it's my first ssrs Chart. I made a chart data with 3 values and a date category group. It gives something like
[image]

my client would like the same chart but by grouping all 3 bars in an unic bar with 3 existing colors. 
[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I found it. I had just to change the chart type to stacked column